# How do I find my iOS device's RAM?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory

Is there a way to find how much RAM is installed in my iOS device?

Answer (score 8):

There are a number of free apps that will provide more information about your device’s internals. [Lirium Device Info](https://itunes.apple.com/app/lirum-device-info-lite-system-monitor/id591660734) is one of the better ones.

From the top-left menu, open **This Device** → **System** for details about your device’s RAM. For instance an iPhone 7+ has 3 GB of RAM:

[image]

Note: I am not affiliated with this app or its developer.

Comment: This app only shows how iOS is using the installed RAM for its own purposes, not _"how much RAM is installed in my iOS device"_ as asked by the OP.

Comment: The first line says Total size of RAM memory is 3GB.  Isn't that the same as "how much RAM is installed in my iOS device"

Answer (score 3):

Go to [EveryMac.com's Ultimate Mac Lookup](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/), enter one of the listed iDevice numbers or identifiers, hit lookup and you will get the RAM size.

[image]

Please check the *: Apple provides no official details regarding RAM used by the %iDevice%...

Various sites compile nice single page summaries. The RAM across devices is listed just below the top horizontal line:

- http://iossupportmatrix.com

Comment: Thanks, I was wondering if there's a way to find out from a command-line command too (once I have a terminal app installed, I mean...)